# Как добавить недостающие элементы в массив?

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток.

Изучая тему парсинга строк, возник один вопрос. Если у нас имеется следующий `String[]` массив:

`A1`, `A1\BB1`, `A1\BB1\CCC1`, `A2`, `A2\BB1`, `A2\BB1\CCC1`

и мы уберем 1-й и 3-й элементы, считая с нуля:

`A1`, `A1\BB1\CCC1`, `A2\BB1`, `A2\BB1\CCC1`

можно ли восстановить недостающие элементы, распарсив строки? Как будет правильнее это реализовать?

Благодарю.

Comment: массив по какому то правилу создается ?

Comment: Я так понимаю, это что-то типо структуры папок.

Comment: Да, все верно, имеется некая папочная структура с пропущенными элементами. Позволю немного подкорректировать вопрос.

Comment: У меня вопрос - по какому принципу вы удаляете 1 и 3 элементы и по какому принципу, они должны быть добавлены обратно?

Comment: Да, конечно. По сути это недостающие элементы дерева папок. То есть если имеются элементы `A1` и `A1\BB1\CCC1`, то в таком случае пропущенным окажется элемент `A1\BB1`.

Comment: Касательно отсутствующих элементов, если имеется элемент `A3\BB3\CCC3`, то перед ним идут `A3\BB3` и `A3`. Однако эти элементы, один или оба, могут быть пропущены.

Comment: первый вопрос снят.
массив всегда упорядочен по путям?

Comment: Да, по сути, именно так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Converter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] test = {"A", "A\\B\\C\\D\\E", "A\\B\\M\\Y"};
        for(String s : normalizePath(test))
            System.out.print(s + ", ");
        System.out.println();
    }


    /*
    Основной метод, возвращающий правильный массив.
     */
    public static String[] normalizePath(String[] s) {
        Node root = makeTree(s);

        ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Map.Entry<String, Node> e : root.getChildren().entrySet())
            addToRes(result, e.getValue(), "");
        return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);

    }

    /*
    Вспомогательный метод для рекурсивного обхода дерева
     */
    private static void addToRes(ArrayList<String> result, Node n, String parent) {
        String currentPath = parent.equals("") ? n.getVal() : parent + "\\" + n.getVal();

        result.add(currentPath);
        for (Map.Entry<String, Node> e : n.getChildren().entrySet())
            addToRes(result, e.getValue(), currentPath);
    }

    /*
    Создатель дерева
     */
    private static Node makeTree(String[] s) {
        Node root = new Node("");

        for (String path : s) {
            Node node = root;
            for (String name : path.split("\\\\")) {
                node = addVal(node, name);
            }
        }

        return root;
    }

    /*
    Вспомогательный метод создателя дерева
    */
    private static Node addVal(Node node, String val) {
        if (node.getVal().equals(val))
            return node;

        Map<String, Node> children = node.getChildren();
        if (children.containsKey(val))
            return children.get(val);

        Node newNode = new Node(val);
        children.put(val, newNode);
        return newNode;
    }


    /*
    Элемент дерева
     */
    private static class Node {
        private Map<String, Node> children = new HashMap<String, Node>();
        private String val;

        public Node(String val) {this.val = val;}

        public Map<String, Node> getChildren() {return children;}

        public String getVal() {return val;}
    }
}
```

Результат

```
A, A\B, A\B\C, A\B\C\D, A\B\C\D\E, A\B\M, A\B\M\Y,
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Программа отлично работает с любыми входными данными.

Comment: @Dmitry08 Пожалуйста. Задачка заинтересовала, решил оформить в код. Намудрил с HashMap'ом только, но переделывать было уже лень. :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно.
Дам общую идею алгоритма:

В цикле проходите элементы массива (строки со слэшами) и строите дерево, создавая соотв. ветвь для каждого элемента: разбиваете строку (очередной элемент массива) по слешам ("a\b\c" -> "a", "b", "c", напр. str.split("\\\\"), становитесь на вершину дерева и смотрите, есть ли ветвь для первого эл-та разбиения ("a"), если нету - создаете. Берете найденную или созданную ветвь, переходите к след. эл-ту разбиения и повторяете процедуру, и так далее, пока не дойдете до конца разбиения. Можно рекурсивно.

Затем обходите дерево и строите для каждого его элемента строку с перечислением всех вершин от корня до данного элемента (опять же, можно рекурсивно - да по-другому и неудобно будет).

Comment: Большое спасибо, попытаюсь реализовать данный вариант.

Answer (score -2):

попробуйте так

```
String path="";
for(int i=0;i<yourArray.lenght;i++)
    path+=(","+yourArray[i]);
```

Затем восстанавливаем старый массив `String newArray=path.split(",")`

Comment: Но здесь имеется один момент: в операторе for текущего массива будет пройдено всего 4 элемента. В исходном их на 2 элемента больше.

Comment: Эти действие можно выполнить перед удалением элементов

Comment: С Вашего позволения, немного уточню вопрос. Изначачально у нас имеются лишь 4 элемента и требуется восстановить недостающие 2.

Comment: Ну тогда List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();

Comment: list.addAll(yourArray); list.add(firstValue,1); list.add(secondValue,3)

Comment: Dmitry08, это кардинально меняет условия, и ответ на задачу - ДА.
Да, вы можете распарсить каждый элемент, упорядочить и убрать лишнее. В Java 8 это можно проделать stream'ами

Comment: Это не решение задачи, это просто создание новой копии прочитанного массива.

Comment: @IvanZelenskyy Пардон, нельзя ли это показать на примере `A1\BB1\CCC1`. Увы, я пока еще newbie в этой теме..

Comment: Да, я говорю именно о создании копии массива. Если речь идёт о добавлении в тот же массив, то вероятно, в нем должны быть тогда пропуски.

Comment: Пожалуй проще, да, реализовать через копию.